# Android: Force display of fragment's scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-scrollbar

I have a PreferenceFragment inside an activity. The PreferenceFragment has many items and can be scroll down. To make sure the user notice it, I would like to force the display of the scroll bar.

I have read that it is usually done with:

```
setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false)
```

or

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

It is not clear to me how to use this property on a fragment (if possible).

Comment: Still looking for an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When the view has been created in the PreferenceFragment,you can use this method:

> getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list).setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

For example:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.findViewById(android.R.id.list).setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        //...
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for PreferenceFragment subclasses. Any ideas?

Comment: Fortunately there are some other ways to do this, `            #setScrollBarFadeDuration(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`, and `#.setScrollBarDefaultDelayBeforeFade(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` in your custom theme.

Or if you aren't using a custom theme, just make one and make your current theme the parent

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
</style>
```

Now just call your "SettingsTheme" in your manifest file for that activity where your preferenceFragment is